# Training neural network with keras (observed loss is too low)

Tags: machine-learning, neural-network, deep-learning, keras

I am training a neural network with Keras which takes input of 2000 X 1 arrays, all the input data are "0" and "1" and generate a single output either 0 or 1.

here is my model:

```
def mdl_normal(sq_len,broker_num):
  model = Sequential()
  model.add(Dense(sq_len * (broker_num + 1), input_dim = (sq_len * (broker_num+1)),activation = 'relu'))
  model.add(Dense(800, activation = 'relu'))
  model.add(Dense(400, activation = 'relu'))
  model.add(Dense(1, activation = 'sigmoid'))
  model.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy', optimizer='SGD')
  return model
```

However I am getting the following while training:

Epoch 384/600 0s - loss: 1.4224e-04 - val_loss: 2.6322

The loss is extremely low and I am wondering I am doing something wrong. Can someone explain what is the meaning of loss here?

Thanks!

Louis

Comment: This behaviour is perfectly fine. You are learning some very very simple model (only one binary feature -> one binary feature) with a huge neural-network and without any regulization. The NN is able to memorize each sample and obtain zero-like loss (of course that's overfitting as seen with the val_loss). You should read some general machine-learning tutorial (keywords: model-capabilities/assumptions; overfitting; regulization).

Comment: Thanks so much! The information helped me a lot